# The "add / show 1 more comments" link doesn't do anything if you don't have comment permissions

Tags: bug, status-reproduced, design, comments, user-interface

I recently lost commenting permissions due to offering a bounty.

Since then, I've noticed that when reading answers with comments, clicking on the "add / show 1 more comments" link doesn't reveal the recently added comment.

[image]

This link appears when a new comment is added to the discussion after you've loaded the page. It worked while I had commenting permissions. It doesn't work now.

It makes sense to not allow me to actually *add* a comment, but I shouldn't be prevented from *showing* the recently added comment, especially because I can view it if I reload the page.

---

I confirmed that it isn't a problem local to my browser by visiting this question from a different browser as a non-logged in user and I could reproduce the issue:

[image]

The "add / show 1 more comments" link doesn't work when you don't have comment permissions or are not logged in.

---

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open a second browser that doesn't have you logged into stackexchange.
2. As your logged in user, here, in this browser window, add a comment to this question.
3. Notice the "add / show 1 more comments" link appear in the other browswer, that you're not logged in with.
4. Click on that link.

Comment: Reproduced (Chrome, Windows 8.1)

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome, 8.1. There, you now have all three types of diamond reproducing your bug :P

Comment: There are *types* of diamonds?? :) I should add, I produced this bug on Safari 6.0.5 and Chrome 30.0.1599.101 on OS X 10.8.4.

Comment: @Sancho Normal moderators (like me), community managers (like Shog), and developers (like Ben). Some other employees not falling within these categories have network diamonds too, but if any there aren't many of them.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when the site starts acting up the problem is local to your browser. Trying

- forcibly reloading the page
- if that fails clearing your caches

There shouldn't be a connection between the ability to *make* comments and the ability to *see* them.

Comment: I *am* able to see the comments when I reload the page. The issue is regarding the functionality of link.